what is difference between "trumping preemption," "preemption," and "not trumping"?
I'm reading Lewis's paper "Causation as Influence," and I understand the example of the Major-Sergeant command as a case of trumping preemption, while the example of Suzy and Billy throwing a rock is seen as a case of preemption. What are the differences between the two, and what do these differences entail?
The former example appears to directly overwhelm because there is a direct condition given that renders the sergeant's command ineffective due to the major's command. In contrast, in the latter example, although Suzy's rock reaches the bottle first, making it seem as if it indirectly overwhelms and prevents Billy's rock from breaking the bottle, there seems to be no clear overwhelming difference between the two. Are there other distinct differences between them? Are there cases where something is problematic in one scenario but not in the other?
